# Uploading an image using php from html file, with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, html

I have an into some snag when tying to design a "my profile editor" for a potential website. The code below is what I'm using and you can see that the "avatar" is the picture file, so id appreciate any advice on how to approach and solve this problem.

```
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passverif'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar'], $_POST['skill']))
                {
                    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                    {
                        $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
                        $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
                        $_POST['passverif'] = stripslashes($_POST['passverif']);
                        $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);

                        $_POST['skill'] = stripslashes($_POST['skill']);
                        $_POST['avatar'] = stripslashes($_POST['avatar']);
                    }
                    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
                    {
                        if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
                        {
                            if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',$_POST['email']))
                            {
                                $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
                                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,sha1( $_POST['password']));
                                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
                                $skill = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['skill']);

                                $avatar = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['avatar']);
                                $dn = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, 'select count(*) as nb from users where username="'.$username.'"'));
                                if($dn['nb']==0 or $_POST['username']==$_SESSION['username'])
                                {
                                    if(mysqli_query($connection,'update users set username="'.$username.'", password="'.$password.'", email="'.$email.'",skill="'.$skill.'", avatar="'.$avatar.'" where id="'.mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['userid']).'"'))
                                    {
                                        $form = false;
                                        unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
            ?>              
            <div class="login-mail">
            <div class="message">Your profile have successfully been edited. You must login again.<br />
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $form = true;
                                        $message = 'An error occured while editing your profile.';
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $form = true;
                                    $message = 'Another user already uses this username.';
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $form = true;
                                $message = 'The email you typed is not valid.';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $form = true;
                            $message = 'Your password must have a minimum of 6 characters.';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $form = true;
                        $message = 'The passwords you entered are not identical.';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $form = true;
                }
                if($form)
                {
                    if(isset($message))
                    {
                        echo '<strong>'.$message.'</strong>';
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']))
                    {
                        $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
                        {
                            $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $password = '';
                        }
                        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $skill = htmlentities($_POST['skill'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $avatar = htmlentities($_POST['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $dnn = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, 'select username,email,avatar,skill from users where username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"'));
                        $username = htmlentities($dnn['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $password = '';
                        $email = htmlentities($dnn['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $skill = htmlentities($dnn['skill'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        $avatar = htmlentities($dnn['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

                    }
            ?>

                <!--gallery-->
                <form action="profile.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/for m-data">
                <div class=" profile">

                    <div class="profile-bottom">
                        <h3><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</h3>
                        <div class="profile-bottom-top">
                        <div class="col-md-4 profile-bottom-img">
                        <img value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo ' '.htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>">

                        </div>


                        <div class="profile-bottom-top">            

                                <h3>You can edit your informations:</h3>
                            <div>
                                <h4><?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo ' '.htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?></h4><br />
                            </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">                          
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Username</h5>:<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /><br /></div>
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Password <span class="small">(6 characters min.)</span></h5> :<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /><br /></div>
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Password <span class="small">(verification)</span></h5> :<input type="password" name="passverif" id="passverif" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /><br /></div>
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Email</h5>:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /><br /></div>
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Skills</h5>:<input type="text" name="skill" id="skill" value="<?php echo $skill; ?>" /><br /></div>
                                        <div class="login-mail">
                                            <h5>Select image to upload</h5>:<h6><input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" value="<?php echo $avatar; ?>"></h6></div>
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="profile-bottom-bottom">
                        <div  class="col-md-6 login-do">
                            <label class="hvr-shutter-in-horizontal login-sub">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-bottom-bottom">
                        <div class="col-md-4 profile-fo">
                            <h4>23,5k</h4>
                            <p>Followers</p>
                            <a href="#" class="pro"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Follow</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 profile-fo">
                            <h4>348</h4>
                            <p>Following</p>
                            <a href="#" class="pro1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>View Profile</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 profile-fo">
                            <h4>23,5k</h4>
                            <p>Snippets</p>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Options</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
            ?>

            <div class="login-mail">
            <div class="message"><h3>To access this page, you must be logged In.</h3><br />
            <a href="signin.php"><h3>Log in</h3></a>
            </div>

            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Well I'm trying to make edit your profile info, which includes uploading your photo... and i don't know how to display the picture you have uploaded in the "", so Im just asking for your advice on how to do that, I'd also appreciate if u can tinker with my code to enable that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You refer to 'this problem'. Try to tell us what your problem exactly is. That would also be helpful to you, because understanding what's the problem is half the work of solving it. PS: It is not good practice to store image files in your database, it can be done, but you shouln't. Store files on disk and refer to them from the database.

Comment: Well I'm trying to make edit your profile info, which includes uploading your photo... and i don't know how to display the picture you have uploaded in the "<IMG>", so Im just asking for your advice on how to do that, I'd also appreciate if u can tinker with my code to enable that

Comment: Can you put that information in your question, not in a comment? Try to be even more specific, if you can. You have to realize your code is very long, and we don't have your database to test your code. So it's hard for us to 'tinker' with your code. You could reduce your code to the bare essentials. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks , this is my first time useing stackflow

Comment: I know, no problem. :-)

Comment: Thanks haha, okay can you have a look at the lines of code that have "avatar" inthem! ,They are the code involving the image file

Comment: Does storing the avatar in the database work? In other words, your problem is retrieving it and showing it in an image tag only?

Comment: Yes when I upload is saves it in the myphpadmin, but what I can't do is display the uploaded image as a profile picture

Comment: What I'm scared of is if its saving the image name and not the image itself

Comment: Those are two conflicting comments: Either you have uploaded the image data, or not. Your form seems oke, but your handling of file submission not. I don't see how you could store the image data in the database this way. See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking ur time to help me out hey, I see where I went wrong

Comment: Ah, oke, that's good. For retrieving the image, and to put it in an `<IMG>` tag, you have to create a seperate PHP file that streams the image from the database to the output. Use that PHP file as the `src="...."` in your  `<IMG>` tag. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php and do not forget the headers. Again: It's much better to store images as the files they are, on disk.

Comment: Haha no wonder it was just displaying the name when I was useing that string ahahah thanks again